# Android execution JavaScript in redirect webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

I am calling primary URL like "https://foo.com/default?companyId=1929770&authorizationSource=FTP", 
When I load primary URL I will be redirected to secondary URL like "https://foo.com/default?companyId=1929770&authorizationSource=FTP_123456789". Secondary URL always generates FTP with number at the end randomly. How I can execute javascript for the secondary URL?

```
public class ActivityWebViewPay extends Activity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String privatURL = "https://foo.com/default?companyId=1929770&authorizationSource=FTP&account=" + getIntent().getStringExtra(ACCOUNT_LS);

    WebView urlWebView = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(urlWebView);
    urlWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    urlWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    WebSettings settingsURL = urlWebView.getSettings();
    settingsURL.setMinimumFontSize(18);
    settingsURL.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    settingsURL.setDisplayZoomControls(true);
    settingsURL.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settingsURL.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    urlWebView.clearHistory();
    urlWebView.clearCache(true);
    urlWebView.loadUrl(privatURL);

    urlWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl("javascript:function a(){window.document.getElementsByClassName('property-info-wrap')[0].style.display='none';}; a()");
        }
    });
}
```

**logcat:**

```
[INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined", source:  (1)
[INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined", source:  (1)
[INFO:CONSOLE(22)] "Start Referrer is >>> ", source: link without FTP (22)
[INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined", source:  (1)
[INFO:CONSOLE(5)] "The key "target-densitydpi" is not supported.", source: link with FTP (5)
[INFO:CONSOLE(30)] "referer ", source: link with FTP (30)
[INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined", source:  (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can execute js code like this inside onPageFinished

```
String jsScript = "javascript:alert(" + msg + ");";
webView.loadUrl(jsScript);
```

Also, for me: i'm adding a switch to know the number of url that i'm openning:

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
{
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    count++;
    switch (count)
    {
        case 1:
            String jsScriptInit;// do that you want
            webView.loadUrl(jsScriptInit);
            break;
        case 2:
            String jsScript;
            webView.loadUrl(jsScript);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: it's works fine for me. try to add some logs. inside onPageFinished() and i hope you will have a succes